# Some folders not included when building a maven project

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, maven, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make a typical maven based Servlet project with JSP, For the view component I have used Twitter Bootstrap but when I try to build the project none of the bootstrap folders like **CSS**, **JS** etc comes in the WAR file.

1. Do I need to make any changes in POM for that?
2. Am I only allowed to create JSP files not HTML files too?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that you needed a jar file for twitter bootstrap and that was missing. Add the following dependency in POM.XML

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.efsavage.twitter.bootstrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-maven</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

then rebuild the project and it will work.